# Excel formula AVERAGEIFS i think

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use AVERAGEIFS not sure if that's the best but here is the issue. Reporting in the new year is a PITA, the spreadsheet has dates in column A with the corresponding value in column B in 7 day increments for example Cell A1 1/7/18 Cell B1 95%,  Cell A2 1/14/18 Cell B2 100%, Cell A3 1/21/18 Cell B3 62%, this goes on for the entire year. In a different cell, say C1 id like to see the average for January, in cell C2 Feb and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are not trying to proportion the percentage in a week that straddles January to February then this for January,

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B, A:A, ">="&DATE(2018, ROW(1:1), 1), A:A, "<"&DATE(2018, ROW(1:1)+1, 1))
```

Fill down for subsequent months.

Comment: Greatly appreciated, working with it now, I'll get right back

Comment: Ok, I have this one kind of working, I'm struggling with the date a little, January works perfectly, as for feb, I changed the +1 to +2 but that gives the running average from Jan and Feb

Comment: No, you **Fill down for subsequent months**. row(1:1) becomes row(2:2) for feb. Leave the +1 alone.

Comment: Perfect, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Simplest to add another column with month or month and year (if you have multiple years worth of data), e.g. in C1 copied down

`=MONTH(A1)`

....and then average for January is simply

`=AVERAGEIF(C:C,1,B:B)`

Repeat for other months

Comment: You guys are quick, I wasn't expecting a response so quick, I'm playing with both now

Comment: This work too, for the sake of keeping the spreadsheet as clean as possible I'm going to use the Jeeped formula but thank you very much